# Can't interpolate frames with pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

So I was trying to test an algorithm I found in a github page that interpolates frames. I was testing the algorithm on the datasets middlebury provided, the link: http://vision.middlebury.edu/flow/data/ .(I use the coloured ones with only two frames. The error also occured in the Yosemite image file) The algorithm worked fine on every image except the last one. It raises the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "run.py", line 257, in  
tensorInputFirst = torch.FloatTensor(numpy.rollaxis(numpy.asarray(PIL.Image.open(arguments_strFirst))[:,:,::-1], 2, 0).astype(numpy.float32) / 255.0) 
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I know what the error means, an index thats not in the list, but I don't know its connection with frame interpolation and why does it happen. Can somebody help.

The code I found on [github](https://github.com/dagf2101/pytorch-sepconv/blob/master/run.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import sys
import getopt
import math
import numpy
import torch
import torch.utils.serialization
import PIL
import PIL.Image

from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_reader import FFMPEG_VideoReader
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_writer import FFMPEG_VideoWriter

from SeparableConvolution import SeparableConvolution # the custom SeparableConvolution layer

torch.cuda.device(1) 

torch.backends.cudnn.enabled = True 

##########################################################

arguments_strModel = 'lf'
arguments_strFirst = './images/first.png'
arguments_strSecond = './images/second.png'
arguments_strOut = './result.png'
arguments_strVideo = ''
arguments_strVideoOut = ''

for strOption, strArgument in getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], '', [ strParameter[2:] + '=' for strParameter in sys.argv[1::2] ])[0]:
    if strOption == '--model':
        arguments_strModel = strArgument # which model to use, l1 or lf, please see our paper for more details

    elif strOption == '--first':
        arguments_strFirst = strArgument # path to the first frame

    elif strOption == '--second':
        arguments_strSecond = strArgument # path to the second frame

    elif strOption == '--out':
        arguments_strOut = strArgument # path to where the output should be stored

    elif strOption == '--video':
        arguments_strVideo = strArgument # path to the video

    elif strOption == '--video-out':
        arguments_strVideoOut = strArgument # path to the video


##########################################################

class Network(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Network, self).__init__()

        def Basic(intInput, intOutput):
            return torch.nn.Sequential(
                torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=intInput, out_channels=intOutput, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
                torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=False),
                torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=intOutput, out_channels=intOutput, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
                torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=False),
                torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=intOutput, out_channels=intOutput, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
                torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=False)
            )


        def Subnet():
            return torch.nn.Sequential(
                torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
                torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=False),
                torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
                torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=False),
                torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=51, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
                torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=False),
                torch.nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear'),
                torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=51, out_channels=51, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
            )

        self.moduleConv1 = Basic(6, 32)
        self.modulePool1 = torch.nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)

        self.moduleConv2 = Basic(32, 64)
        self.modulePool2 = torch.nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)

        self.moduleConv3 = Basic(64, 128)
        self.modulePool3 = torch.nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)

        self.moduleConv4 = Basic(128, 256)
        self.modulePool4 = torch.nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)

        self.moduleConv5 = Basic(256, 512)
        self.modulePool5 = torch.nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)

        self.moduleDeconv5 = Basic(512, 512)
        self.moduleUpsample5 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear'),
            torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=False)
        )

        self.moduleDeconv4 = Basic(512, 256)
        self.moduleUpsample4 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear'),
            torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=False)
        )

        self.moduleDeconv3 = Basic(256, 128)
        self.moduleUpsample3 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear'),
            torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=False)
        )

        self.moduleDeconv2 = Basic(128, 64)
        self.moduleUpsample2 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear'),
            torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=False)
        )

        self.moduleVertical1 = Subnet()
        self.moduleVertical2 = Subnet()
        self.moduleHorizontal1 = Subnet()
        self.moduleHorizontal2 = Subnet()

        self.modulePad = torch.nn.ReplicationPad2d([ int(math.floor(51 / 2.0)), int(math.floor(51 / 2.0)), int(math.floor(51 / 2.0)), int(math.floor(51 / 2.0)) ])

        self.load_state_dict(torch.load('./network-' + arguments_strModel + '.pytorch'))

    def forward(self, variableInput1, variableInput2):
        variableJoin = torch.cat([variableInput1, variableInput2], 1)

        variableConv1 = self.moduleConv1(variableJoin)
        variablePool1 = self.modulePool1(variableConv1)

        variableConv2 = self.moduleConv2(variablePool1)
        variablePool2 = self.modulePool2(variableConv2)

        variableConv3 = self.moduleConv3(variablePool2)
        variablePool3 = self.modulePool3(variableConv3)

        variableConv4 = self.moduleConv4(variablePool3)
        variablePool4 = self.modulePool4(variableConv4)

        variableConv5 = self.moduleConv5(variablePool4)
        variablePool5 = self.modulePool5(variableConv5)

        variableDeconv5 = self.moduleDeconv5(variablePool5)
        variableUpsample5 = self.moduleUpsample5(variableDeconv5)

        variableDeconv4 = self.moduleDeconv4(variableUpsample5 + variableConv5)
        variableUpsample4 = self.moduleUpsample4(variableDeconv4)

        variableDeconv3 = self.moduleDeconv3(variableUpsample4 + variableConv4)
        variableUpsample3 = self.moduleUpsample3(variableDeconv3)

        variableDeconv2 = self.moduleDeconv2(variableUpsample3 + variableConv3)
        variableUpsample2 = self.moduleUpsample2(variableDeconv2)

        variableCombine = variableUpsample2 + variableConv2

        variableDot1 = SeparableConvolution()(self.modulePad(variableInput1), self.moduleVertical1(variableCombine), self.moduleHorizontal1(variableCombine))
        variableDot2 = SeparableConvolution()(self.modulePad(variableInput2), self.moduleVertical2(variableCombine), self.moduleHorizontal2(variableCombine))

        return variableDot1 + variableDot2


moduleNetwork = Network().cuda()

##########################################################

def process(tensorInputFirst, tensorInputSecond, tensorOutput):
    assert(tensorInputFirst.size(1) == tensorInputSecond.size(1))
    assert(tensorInputFirst.size(2) == tensorInputSecond.size(2))

    intWidth = tensorInputFirst.size(2)
    intHeight = tensorInputFirst.size(1)

    assert(intWidth <= 1280) # while our approach works with larger images, we do not recommend it unless you are aware of the implications
    assert(intHeight <= 720) # while our approach works with larger images, we do not recommend it unless you are aware of the implications

    intPaddingLeft = int(math.floor(51 / 2.0))
    intPaddingTop = int(math.floor(51 / 2.0))
    intPaddingRight = int(math.floor(51 / 2.0))
    intPaddingBottom = int(math.floor(51 / 2.0))
    modulePaddingInput = torch.nn.Module()
    modulePaddingOutput = torch.nn.Module()

    if True:
        intPaddingWidth = intPaddingLeft + intWidth + intPaddingRight
        intPaddingHeight = intPaddingTop + intHeight + intPaddingBottom

        if intPaddingWidth != ((intPaddingWidth >> 7) << 7):
            intPaddingWidth = (((intPaddingWidth >> 7) + 1) << 7) # more than necessary

        if intPaddingHeight != ((intPaddingHeight >> 7) << 7):
            intPaddingHeight = (((intPaddingHeight >> 7) + 1) << 7) # more than necessary

        intPaddingWidth = intPaddingWidth - (intPaddingLeft + intWidth + intPaddingRight)
        intPaddingHeight = intPaddingHeight - (intPaddingTop + intHeight + intPaddingBottom)

        modulePaddingInput = torch.nn.ReplicationPad2d([intPaddingLeft, intPaddingRight + intPaddingWidth, intPaddingTop, intPaddingBottom + intPaddingHeight])
        modulePaddingOutput = torch.nn.ReplicationPad2d([0 - intPaddingLeft, 0 - intPaddingRight - intPaddingWidth, 0 - intPaddingTop, 0 - intPaddingBottom - intPaddingHeight])

    if True:
        tensorInputFirst = tensorInputFirst.cuda()
        tensorInputSecond = tensorInputSecond.cuda()

        modulePaddingInput = modulePaddingInput.cuda()
        modulePaddingOutput = modulePaddingOutput.cuda()

    if True:
        variablePaddingFirst = modulePaddingInput(torch.autograd.Variable(data=tensorInputFirst.view(1, 3, intHeight, intWidth), volatile=True))
        variablePaddingSecond = modulePaddingInput(torch.autograd.Variable(data=tensorInputSecond.view(1, 3, intHeight, intWidth), volatile=True))
        variablePaddingOutput = modulePaddingOutput(moduleNetwork(variablePaddingFirst, variablePaddingSecond))

        tensorOutput.resize_(3, intHeight, intWidth).copy_(variablePaddingOutput.data[0])

    if True:
        tensorInputFirst.cpu()
        tensorInputSecond.cpu()
        tensorOutput.cpu()


tensorOutput = torch.FloatTensor()

if arguments_strVideo and arguments_strVideoOut:
    reader = FFMPEG_VideoReader(arguments_strVideo, False)
    writer = FFMPEG_VideoWriter(arguments_strVideoOut, reader.size, reader.fps*2)
    reader.initialize()
    nextFrame = reader.read_frame()
    for x in range(0, reader.nframes):
        firstFrame = nextFrame
        nextFrame = reader.read_frame()
        tensorInputFirst = torch.FloatTensor(numpy.rollaxis(firstFrame[:,:,::-1], 2, 0) / 255.0)
        tensorInputSecond = torch.FloatTensor(numpy.rollaxis(nextFrame[:,:,::-1], 2, 0) / 255.0)
        process(tensorInputFirst, tensorInputSecond, tensorOutput)
        writer.write_frame(firstFrame)
        writer.write_frame((numpy.rollaxis(tensorOutput.clamp(0.0, 1.0).numpy(), 0, 3)[:,:,::-1] * 255.0).astype(numpy.uint8))
    writer.write_frame(nextFrame)
    writer.close()
else:
    tensorInputFirst = torch.FloatTensor(numpy.rollaxis(numpy.asarray(PIL.Image.open(arguments_strFirst))[:,:,::-1], 2, 0).astype(numpy.float32) / 255.0)
    tensorInputSecond = torch.FloatTensor(numpy.rollaxis(numpy.asarray(PIL.Image.open(arguments_strSecond))[:,:,::-1], 2, 0).astype(numpy.float32) / 255.0) 
    process(tensorInputFirst, tensorInputSecond, tensorOutput)
    PIL.Image.fromarray((numpy.rollaxis(tensorOutput.clamp(0.0, 1.0).numpy(), 0, 3)[:,:,::-1] * 255.0).astype(numpy.uint8)).save(arguments_strOut)
```

**UPDATE**

I found the reason of the error. It is because the image is grayscale while the other images I tested was coloured as coloured ones are 24 bit depth while grayscales are 8 bit depth. How can I modify the code for it to work on grayscale images.

Comment: I suspect you are trying to read gray scale image.

Comment: thats the problem but how can I change the code for it to work for gray scale images